# std::shared_ptr to std::function

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, std-function

How can I use a `shared_ptr` to a function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct S {
    void operator()(int i) {
        cout<< i;
    }
}

int main() {
    
    shared_ptr<std::function<void(int)>> fun = make_shared<S>();
    fun(7);
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this example I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:62: error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr >’ requested
     shared_ptr<std::function<void(int)>> fun = make_shared<S>();
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
main.cpp:16:10: error: no match for call to ‘(std::shared_ptr >) (int)’
     fun(7);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a `shared_ptr<S>` to a `shared_ptr<std::function<void(int)>>` just because you can assign an `S` to a `std::function<void(int)>`.

You could however just make a `std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(int)>>` from an S. The `S` would be the argument passed to `make_shared`, i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct S {
    void operator()(int i) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto fun = std::make_shared<std::function<void(int)>>(S{});
    (*fun)(7);
    return 0;
}
```